# How to install gitlab separate on centos7?

Tags: apache, github, gitlab, centos7, gitlab-omnibus

I wish to install gitlab on my Centos 7 server. But I need to separate the gitlab and apache folder. That is when I type localhost  should get the index page in HTML folder and when I type git.example.com should get the gitlab page. Is there any way to do this? Please help me, anyone.

Comment: Isn't Omnibus GitLab running with NGINX? (mine is...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not be the best solution, but what I did was to set a "front NGINX" to proxy my 3 services: Apache (at www), Redmine (at issues) and GitLab (at git)

Then I configured my Apache to listen on another port (say 808). And my GitLab to listen on its own port (say 809).

And I added a server configuration in NGINX with a proxypass using something like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com;
  location / {
    access_log off;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:808;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

and one for the GitLab as:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name git.example.com;
  location / {
    access_log off;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:809;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
  error_page 502 /502.html;
  location = /502.html {
    root  /opt/gitlab/error_pages;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also consider looking at mod_proxy with ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse on your Apache